# How can i design my country map in html 5?

Tags: html

I want to design a my country map so that, for example, when I click the Province on the map it opens another web page. How can I achieve this? An introduction, link or web page for help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: SO is not for requesting for solutions for a problem you have not tryied yet

Comment: @EnriMR I do not know that how can i implant that.

Comment: Have you search in Google for JavaScript libraries to manage maps? SO is not for thinking or programming for you

Comment: @EnriMR i want work my web site in local network not on internet! i do not to use google map,for example paint country and use it in web site